# Making built.io calls from Spring

Tags: java, spring, built.io, built.io-backend

I have a spring web service which gets data from a form and I am using built.io to store the information. I am not sure how to create built.io objects from my spring client. Do I need to make a rest call with a json object from spring or is there a library?

Comment: Do you understand what built.io is to begin with?

Comment: Right now there is no java sdk available for built.io. You can check the latest ones here https://docs.built.io/downloads

Answer (score 1):

yes, you will have to make REST calls as there is no specific SDK available.